# How to include interaction variables in logit statsmodel python?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I am working on Logistic regression model and I am using statsmodels api's logit. I am unable to figure out how to feed interaction terms to the model.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific, and show where you are stuck, i tried to answer your question below but you might be meaning something else?

Comment: @StupidWolf Thank you. Your answer helped. Basically I wanted to know how to specify the interactions in the parameters. I realize now that I have to do the R thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the formula interface, and use the colon,`:` , inside the formula, for example :

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np
import pandas

np.random.seed(111)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1,0.5,(50,3)),columns=['x1','x2','y'])

res1 = smf.logit(formula='y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2', data=df).fit()

res1.summary()
                           Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                   50
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                       46
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            3
Date:                Thu, 04 Feb 2021   Pseudo R-squ.:                 0.02229
Time:                        10:03:59   Log-Likelihood:                -32.463
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -33.203
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                    0.6869
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     -0.9808      0.677     -1.449      0.147      -2.308       0.346
x1             0.4700      0.851      0.552      0.581      -1.199       2.139
x2             0.9808      0.863      1.137      0.256      -0.710       2.671
x1:x2         -1.1632      1.229     -0.946      0.344      -3.572       1.246
==============================================================================
```

Comment: When do we need to add a constant to the data prior to running the model?

Comment: @Hefe you need to do that when using the normal `statsmodels` api. When using the formula api, the constant is already included. Add `- 1` to the formula to remove the constant. https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html